# Characters do not display in the post body editing box

Tags: bug

I am trying to ask a question right now, but all I can see in the "body" section is a blank space. I am typing-in blindly. I could add a screenshot, but doing that when typing blindly is very hard.

Here is a screenshot as I am editing this: [image]

Another screenshot from worldbuilding:

[image]

Another screenshot: [image]

Comment: Also, the edit has the same problem too. This is not specific to meta, this seems to be happening network-wide, at least for me.

Comment: Browser? Did you try to check if any extensions and/or userscripts might be causing this?

Comment: Any errors in the developer console of your browser? Which browser are you on? Does the same happen on a different network?

Comment: @VLAZ It was working perfectly a few hours ago.

Comment: @rene Nothing relevant on Firefox console.

Comment: Seems to be fixed right now. I won't delete this question, maybe something bad was delivered in a production and it was just reverted, so I will wait and see if any SE-dev shows up.

Comment: Pretty unambiguously looks like a browser/font problem on the client side. Nothing SE should be concerned with.

Comment: Nothing bad was delivered, it's 100% not related to SE. This is something on your side, maybe some rogue software, OS blip, really can't know.

Comment: From the screenshots, it seems similar to [The review close votes queue is not (always) rendering code formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423114) - both of these reports are recent, as well. I suspect there is an underlying reason. A browser update, or OS update, or site update. Or something similar.

Comment: @user3840170 I got that problem this morning for only 2 or 3 hours. And only on SE. No browser, AV, font or anything was updated at my side and the problem was eventually gone just as mysteriously as it came. Also, the broken characters are ASCII characters that every font knows how to render.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars See my previous comment (can't @-call two people in the same comment).

Comment: Well if this would really have been something on SE side, the meta sites would have been flooded with reports, and that didn't happen. I don't blame you at all, but your approach earlier appeared to "blame" SE, and that I wanted to correct. As for why it happened for you only on SE, can't really know, but already seen cases in the past of "antivirus" programs that messed with the JS and CSS of only certain web pages based on their content, to "protect" the user from potential risk. Might be something like this, or some lurking software you have and don't remember.